# Can unpaid/unlicensed college interns edit medical charts in California?

Tags: practice-of-medicine, health-education, medical-records, legal, medical-ethics

I recently took an unpaid internship at a pain management clinic who is asking me to edit SOAP notes and patients' charts. Is it legal for me to even touch this information without even having been accepted to medical school?